# Creating an advanced segment in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a user page path analysis for users who completed a specific event action during the session. So far I have been able to create the page paths for all users - but I'm now trying to create a secondary path analysis for users who contacted.

I tried my best to locate solutions using the where clause but everything has resulted in 0 results showing

```sql
SELECT t.page_path,
        t.second_page_path,
        t.third_page_path,
        t.fourth_page_path,
        #concact the 4 pages together with a hyphen if a next page exists
        CONCAT(t.page_path,IF(t.second_page_path IS NULL,'','*'),
        IFNULL(t.second_page_path,''),IF(t.third_page_path IS NULL,'','*'),
        IFNULL(t.third_page_path,''),IF(t.fourth_page_path IS NULL,'','*'),
        IFNULL(t.fourth_page_path,'')) AS full_page_journey,
        #Count total sessions that went down that path after landing
        count(sessionId) AS total_sessions
FROM (
SELECT
  CONCAT(fullVisitorId,'-', CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) AS sessionId,
  hits.hitNumber as hitsya,
 (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 22) as page_path,  
  LEAD((SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 22)) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS second_page_path,
  LEAD((SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 22),2) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS third_page_path,
  LEAD((SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) x WHERE x.index = 22),3) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS fourth_page_path
FROM
  `PROJECT_NAME.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190501'
  AND '20190505'
  AND hits.type='PAGE'
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, r'Contact Us Submission'))t
 WHERE t.hitsya=1
     #Group by page of hit and all subsequent pages
     GROUP BY t.page_path,
              t.second_page_path,
              t.third_page_path,
              t.fourth_page_path,
              full_page_journey
     ORDER BY total_sessions DESC
```

I am expecting to only get sessions where that event contained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 0 results because your conditions are contradicting:

```sql
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190501'
  AND '20190505'
  AND hits.type='PAGE'
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, r'Contact Us Submission'))t
```

You can't have `hits.type='PAGE'` and expect a value in `hits.eventInfo.eventAction`. This field only contains values for `hits.type='EVENT'`

If you want sessions with this event then look for it using a subquery over the whole session:

```sql
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190501'
  AND '20190505'
  AND hits.type='PAGE'
  AND (SELECT COUNT(1)>0 
   FROM unnest(hits) 
   WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.eventInfo.eventAction, r'Contact Us Submission') )
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning this stuff and I'll try to get your suggestion to work within my query. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, np. If it works, consider accepting my answer :)